# Reselling from a VPS (cloud server)

Tags: vps, cloud-hosting, reseller

I am currently administering about 15 small websites (total bandwidth never exceeds 1.5 GB/month) on a shared reseller host using cPanel and WHM.
I'm about to migrate these sites to a virtual cloud server from Rackspace.

How would I go about implementing features of a managed reseller host on a virtual server (to which I have root access but nothing other than clean OS)? In particular, I would like to:

- Offer control panel access to each domain (specifically email/ftp account management and some form of access to the site's databases)
- Enforce bandwidth limits per account
- Enforce disk space quotas per account
- Manage billing

I'm running Debian lenny on the new cloud instance, and would appreciate answers for any web server (apache, nginx, etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IspCP Omega](http://isp-control.net/). It's a fork of VHCS, and hopefully should cover all the things you mention. I've not used IspCP Omega, but I have used VHCS in the past.